# Running Flask on Pi Zero getting uneven PWMLED

Tags: led, pi-zero-w, gpiozero

This is my first trial run using a Raspberry Pi Zero W to run RGB LEDs following this tutorial: https://dordnung.de/raspberrypi-ledstrip/

I've completed the tutorial, have everything wired up, and running the following python3 code from the command line gives expected results and the LEDs color is consistent.

```
from gpiozero import PWMLED
from time import sleep
import sys

ri = int(sys.argv[1])
gi = int(sys.argv[2])
bi = int(sys.argv[3])

rl = PWMLED(17)
gl = PWMLED(27)
bl = PWMLED(22)

def rgb_toPWM (r,g,b):
    rl.value = r / 255
    gl.value = g / 255
    bl.value = b / 255


rgb_toPWM(ri,gi,bi)
sleep(3)
```

When I wrap it in flask the LEDs flicker and the colors don't match what I give in the code above.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from gpiozero import PWMLED
from time import sleep
import json

rl = PWMLED(17)
gl = PWMLED(27)
bl = PWMLED(22)

def rgb_toPWM (r,g,b):
   rl.value = 0
   gl.value = 0
   bl.value = 0
   rl.value = r / 255
   gl.value = g / 255
   bl.value = b / 255

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
   redValue = 20
   greenValue = 100
   blueValue = 200
   templateData = {
      'title' : 'Pi Zero 00',
      'red_v': redValue,
      'green_v': greenValue,
      'blue_v': blueValue
      }
   return render_template('index.html', **templateData)

@app.route('/changecolor', methods=['POST'])
def changeColor():
   red = int(request.form['red'])
   green = int(request.form['green'])
   blue = int(request.form['blue'])
   rgb_toPWM (red, green, blue)
   data = {}
   data['red_3'] = str(red)
   data['green_3'] = str(green)
   data['blue_3'] = str(blue)
   data['red_digit'] = str(red / 255)
   data['green_digit'] = str(green / 255)
   data['blue_digit'] = str(blue / 255)
   json_data = json.dumps(data)
   sleep(3)
   return json_data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True)
```

I assume this has something to do with flask, but I really have no clue. Here's the output of the above

```
blue_3: "114" blue_digit: "0.4470588235294118"
green_3: "128" green_digit: "0.5019607843137255"  
red_3: "250" red_digit: "0.9803921568627451"
```

I put those same values in the top code and it looks like the color I'd expect, but from the flask code it flickers and "spurts"

OS VERSION="9 (stretch)"

Kernal Linux 4.9.59+ #1047 Sun Oct 29 11:47:10 GMT 2017 armv6l GNU/Linux

Addition: 
I've started just moving one pin at a time and the PWM just doesn't seem consistent, regardless of the value I give it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working using PiGPIOFactory pointing to localhost.

changing

```
rl00 = PWMLED(17)
gl00 = PWMLED(27)
bl00 = PWMLED(22)
```

to and adding

```
fac_loc = PiGPIOFactory(host='127.0.0.1')

rl00 = PWMLED(17, pin_factory=fac_loc)
gl00 = PWMLED(27, pin_factory=fac_loc)
bl00 = PWMLED(22, pin_factory=fac_loc)
```